# How to handle domain status of Amazon elasticsearch service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I created an elasticsearch cluster and uploaded 45 GB of data.There, I tried to changed the access policy of the domain. The domain status has been showing "Processing" for last 24 hours. Is there any way to reset access policy and Why is the domain status still "Processing"?

Comment: having the same issue right now, have you resolved it? @anil

Comment: @DmytriyVoloshyn contact aws customer support. They will resolve it in a day or two.

Comment: yep, I resolved it the same way by contacting aws support.

Answer (score 2):

Part of [the response from AWS support to a similar question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244088):

> Any configuration change we spin up another set of instance and copy the data across to new search domain before we terminate previous set of instances.

So it might be that it's taking them a while to copy that data over and perform any other indexing operations on the new ES instance.